# Replace duplicate adjacent characters with single character using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql, this query:

`select "-foo---baz-beer--" as result`

I want to transform to replace multiple adjacent occurrences of `-` with its single counterpart. Psuedocode:

`select custom_replace("-foo---baz-beer--") as result`

Would return this:

```
-foo-baz-beer-
```

How do do this with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick you can use for this purpose:

```
select replace(replace(replace(col, '-', '><'), '<>', ''), '><', '-')
```